# ngx-datatable css styling for mouse hover

Tags: css, angular, ngx-datatable

I'm using ngx-datatable with the bootstrap theme. I can't find or figure out how to change the styling for when the mouse is hovered over a cells?. In this example it goes grey

http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#css

I've been able to change the activation colour like this, just can't figure out the hover colour.

```
::ng-deep .ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body .datatable-body-
row.active {
  background-color: #006eff;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: You got it to work?

Comment: @C.Schubert , thanks, its working great :-)

Comment: Nice! Could you mark my answer as answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap:not(.cell-selection) .datatable-body-row:hover,
.ngx-datatable.material:not(.cell-selection) .datatable-body-row:hover .datatable-row-group
{ 
   background: red;
}
```

This works.

Comment: copy and paste this doesn't work for me :( is there any variable I need to be aware of please?

Answer (score 3):

```
 :host
  ::ng-deep
  .ngx-datatable.bootstrap:not(.cell-selection)
  .datatable-body-row:hover,
:host
  ::ng-deep
  .ngx-datatable.material:not(.cell-selection)
  .datatable-body-row:hover
  .datatable-row-group {
  background: red;
}
```

I had to add

```
    :host
  ::ng-deep
```

and then it stared working.

You can change other default styles because there is a linear translation:

```
:host
  ::ng-deep
  .ngx-datatable.material:not(.cell-selection)
  .datatable-body-row:hover {
  background-color: #007bff2e;
}
```

Comment: how can i apply similar for selected ? the example they have for selected does not work fo rme !